# How to unpack list into two variables in python2.x

Tags: python, syntax, backwards-compatibility

I would like to unpack the return of a function into :

1. a first variable always set up by the first returned value
2. a second variable to store any exceeded returned value

To do so, I have this code working under python3.x. How could I make it works with python 2.x (python2.6 at least) ?

```
a,*b = ['a','b','c']
```

**Edit:** This would also work with :

```
a,*b = ['a']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to do this in Python 2.7, instead you can create a new list without the first element and first element alone and unpack them into respective variables.

```
data = ['a','b','c']
a, b = data[0], data[1:]
print a, b
```

**Output**

```
a ['b', 'c']
```

This solution will still work, even if the RHS has only one element

```
data = ['a']
a, b = data[0], data[1:]
print a, b
```

**Output**

```
a []
```

Comment: Thank's. My question wasn't precise enougth. See my edit part.

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing:

```
>>> lis = ['a','b','c']
>>> a, b = lis[0], lis[1:]
>>> a
'a'
>>> b
['b', 'c']
```